# Bash script makes connection using FreeTDS, interacts, doesn't exit (just hangs)

Tags: bash, freetds

I'm using FreeTDS in a script to insert records into a MSSQL database. The`USE`and`INSERT`commands work, but the`exit`command doesn't and it hangs. I've tried redirecting`stdout`but`cat`complains. I suppose I will use [Expect](http://www.nist.gov/mel/msid/expect.cfm) otherwise. Meh. Thanks.

`echo -e "USE db\nGO\nINSERT INTO db_table (id, data, meta)\nVALUES (1, 'data', 'meta')\nGO\nexit" > tempfile`
`cat tempfile - | tsql -H 10.10.10.10 -p 1433 -U user -P pass`

Comment: What's wrong with using a heredoc?

Comment: Like this? It's exiting, but not inserting the record.
`tsql -H 10.10.10.10 -p 1433 -U user -P pass <<< tempfile`
Perhaps too many commands too quickly?

Comment: No, a heredoc is two less thans.  `<<<` is a here string, which is something different.

Comment: And in that case, what you really want is just `< tempfile`, which is standard input redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to do this: `cat tempfile -`?  It means that it will wait for you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, because it is trying to read from standard input as well.

If not, remove the `-`.

Also, as Ignacio suggests, you could write it more cleanly as a heredoc:

```
tsql -H 10.10.10.10 -p 1433 -U user -P pass <<EOF
USE db
GO
INSERT INTO db_table (id, data, meta)
VALUES (1, 'data', 'meta')
GO
exit
EOF
```

Or just do the echo with literal newlines rather than `\n`:

```
echo "
USE db
GO
INSERT INTO db_table (id, data, meta)
VALUES (1, 'data', 'meta')
GO
exit
" > tempfile
```

and then run it by using standard input redirection (`<`) like this:

```
tsql -H 10.10.10.10 -p 1433 -U user -P pass < tempfile
```

Comment: Awesome. No, I didn't mean to leave the `cat tempfile -` it was in there from something else I was trying. The EOF is much cleaner though. Thanks again.